# iOS 7 MKOverlayRenderer Not Working

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm updating an iOS 6 app for iOS 7 and discovered that the way overlays are handled has completely changed in iOS 7.

We're drawing a light grey overlay over the entire map. In iOS 6 everything works perfectly, in iOS 7 we get no overlay.

In `viewDidLoad` I have the following:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCoords[4] = { {90,-180}, {90,180}, {-90,180}, {-90,-180} };
MKPolygon *worldOverlay = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:worldCoords
                                                      count:4];
[self.mapView addOverlay:worldOverlay];
```

Then, for iOS 6 . . .

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if (![overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon *)overlay;
    MKPolygonView *view = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithPolygon:polygon];
    view.fillColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];
    return view;
}
```

For iOS 7 . . .

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay
{
    if (![overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
        return nil;
    }
    MKPolygon *polygon = (MKPolygon *)overlay;
    MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:polygon];
    renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor darkGrayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4];    
    return renderer;
}
```

Using breakpoints, I verified that the `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` method is being called and that the `renderer` object it's returning has the `fillColor` property set correctly.

Any thoughts as to why we're not seeing the overlay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of your code is absolutely valid - I plugged it into my test map controller and it works perfectly if I do one small change:

```
    CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCoords[4] = { {43,-100}, {43,-80}, {25,-80}, {25,-100} };
```

So, the problem is not in the renderer per se. I believe it has something to do with specifying 180th Meridian - Apple has made some changes to support regions spanning the 180th Meridian in iOS7. I don't need it since focusing exclusively on North America so I skipped it but there is a 2013 WWDC video where they talk about it - see What's New in MapKit session around 4:42: https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you @Vitali. I suspected it may have something to do with the changes Apple made. After I posted the question I tried the following:     `CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCoords[4] = { {80,-170}, {80,170}, {-80,170}, {-80,-170} };`, which didn't work. Right now I'm only working with North America as well so, based on your answer, I changed it to `CLLocationCoordinate2D worldCoords[4] = { {72,-168}, {-2,-98}, {18,-57}, {-38,68} };`, which works.

Answer (score 1):

I tried numerous times, and finally find a map of the world covered the entire way.
Apple does not know how to engage sdk, you must add two polygons, map of the world will be divided into two parts. And added to the overlay.
These two parts of the boundary definition is:

```
 var ccoodsW = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[] {
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = 85.9809906974076,Longitude = -179.999999644933 },
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = -80.9793991796858,Longitude = -179.999999644933},
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = -80.97939920061767,Longitude = 0},
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = 85.9809906974076 ,Longitude = 0}
             };

        var ccoodsE = new CLLocationCoordinate2D[] {
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = 85.9809906974076,Longitude = 0 },
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = -80.9793991796858,Longitude = 0},
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = -80.97939920061767,Longitude = 179.999999644933},
                 new CLLocationCoordinate2D(){ Latitude = 85.9809906974076 ,Longitude = 179.999999644933}
             };
```

btw:
i'm using xamarin for ios